# Facebook| Handling Like button clicks

Tags: facebook

I would like to handle user clicks for Like button.
I copied the generated code exactly from the [Like button documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)
to page, but every time I click the Like button, nothing happens.

I've read all questions related to this issue but nothing works. 
I know this question has been asked many times, but this issue is driving me crazy.

I am using Firefox.

Here is my complete HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Facebook Like Button</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'MY_APP_ID', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function () {
            alert('Like button is clicked');
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>


   <fb:like href="http://www.bluelink.ws/" send="true" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have left the MY_APP_ID as it is in the Example, this needs to be an actual Application ID, not the Text String from the example.

Also its worth in chrome/firefox opening the JS console to monitor for Errors/console messages.

And check your URL that you are liking in the Facebook Linter: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to check your sites OG Tags

Comment: Of course I use an actual App ID,
JS console shows nothing, the debug tools returned response 200.
Any ideas? Thank you Barry

Comment: Try using the HTML5 version, rather than the fb:like version.